# How to check if a file is a Python file in Python language

Tags: python, django, validation, python-3.6

I'm working on a web application where candidates submit python code and the platform passes them through a unit test which is written by the recruiters.
I'm using Django and I'm having trouble validating the unit-test file.
How to test if a file is a python file and that it's correctly formed (no Syntax or lexical errors)? using Python ?

Thanks

Comment: will look for that, didn't know it was a thing... thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `compile`. Pass the content of the file as a string as the first param, file from which the code was read (If it wasn't read from a file, you can give a name yourself) as the second param and `mode` as the third.

Try:

```
with open("full/file/path.py") as f:
    try:
        compile(f.read(), 'your_code_name', 'exec')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

In case the content of the test file is:

```
print 1
```

The `compile` function will throw a `SyntaxError` and the following message will be printed:

```
Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(1)? (your_code_name, line 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, a great example !